# Focus an enter key to a specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently facing a problem.

I need have a form to be fill by a user ie:

```
field1: <input type='text' name='field1'>
field1: <input type='text' name='field1'>
<input type='button' value='Save' name='Save'>
```

So now I need the way to focus on the 'Save' button when a user has filled the last text box in a form, so that even when the user clicks on the 'Enter' button the save event get run.

This usually happens automatically but the problem is I have many buttons in my page, now when a user click on save another click event(that I don't want) gets fired up.

So my question is how do I control what should happen when the ENTER button is clicked, or should I disable this event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to accomplish that is by using javascript, and I'd suggest you using jQuery.

```
$('#mytextfield').change(function(e) {
    $('input[type=submit]').focus();
});
```

You can also autofocus an element on HTML5 by adding the attribute autofocus="autofocus"

Take a look at the small demo : http://jsfiddle.net/9WmQ5/

Comment: Thanks I will try this. But wouldn't it loose focus on the 'mytextfield' field?

Comment: @Sboniso Marcus Nzimande http://jsfiddle.net/9WmQ5/  created a fiddle for you check it out...

Comment: nice example, the problem I am facing is that my page consists of 2 types of buttons. There is `type='submit'`, and `type='image'`. So what happens is the focus is always on the `type='submit'` button, but I need it to be on the `type='image'` when the user is finished filling the form.

Answer (score 2):

you have to put the button inside the form

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value='Save' name='Save'>
</form>
```

in that way when you press enter the event will be executed
remeber type="submit"

Comment: I get what you mean but my buttons are of type='image'.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to listen which key is pressed

```
function keyPressListener(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                 // do something
    }
}
```

and then add onkeypress attribute to your input textbox

```
onkeypress="keyPressListener(event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help to solve

```
field1: <input type='text' name='field1'>
field1: <input type='text' name='field1' id='last-name'>
<input type='button' value='Save' id='save-btn' name='Save'>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#last-name').blur(function(){ $('#save-btn').focus(); });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using JQuery,

```
document.getElementById('idName').focus();
```

Above line is used focus your element

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Form element, you can also specify the button types accordingly. Focus event will give priority to type 'submit' as compared to type 'button'

```
    //HTML
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form_field">
        <input formControlName="otpcode" id="otpcode" matInput 
            placeholder="Enter OTP" type="text">
            <mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.get('otpcode').valid && 
                loginForm.get('otpcode').touched"
                 class="text-danger small position-absolute">This 
                 field is required
            </mat-error>
       </mat-form-field>

      <button type="button" mat-raised-button> Resend OTP </button>
      <button type="submit" mat-raised-button> Login </button>
    </form>

    //TS
   loginForm: FormGroup;
```